# RestKit can't map keys that don't exist in the source representation?

Tags: restkit

stack guys.
Recently, I process the net request with restkit, but if I want to add some key-value pairs that doesn't exist in the source representation, (such as the "userid", which is for user switch), I must add this in the success block, this is very boring. So, is there any convenient way to solve this?

Comment: So you want to modify the mapped objects to add additional data that isn't received from the server? And you want to do it during the mapping?

Comment: Yes, for instance, the "userid" I mentioned in the question, and there are also some other key-values, if handled them in the success block, it's boring

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to override `willSave` method in your managed object subclass and, if the id isn't set, create and set it. This will update the objects during the mapping process (and is a lot easier than editing the JSON).

Comment: thank you, I'll check the source code and learn how to use the willSave method